# problem when adding crystarl reports references with nant

Tags: crystal-reports, reference, nant, report

This is the problem. I have been trying to compile a simple desktop vb aplication using the solution task found in nant. When I compile it without crystarl reports controls it compiles ok, but when add a simple crystal report viewer It does not compile any more. I supose I have to make some kind of reference but since these assemblys are in the GAC like System.* assemblys they shouldn't be a problem.

This is the very simple code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="miPrueba" default="go">
<target name="go">
 <solution configuration="debug" solutionfile="simple.sln"/>
</target>
</project>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So, as I suspected, this was very simple. Here is what I did to fix it. Simply copy the dlls of crystal reports into the bin directory, delete the crystal references in the project, if any,and make the references again pointing to the bin directory.